# Best way to validate a LinkedIn member ID (in PHP)

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I'm working on a application using LinkedIn authentication as a log-in.  Could anyone advise on the best way to validate a LinkedIn member ID?

Is it always a set number of characters (10?) and alphanumeric?  Could use [strlen](https://www.php.net/strlen) == 10 and [ctype_alnum](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alpha.php) to test this but wondered if anyone had any other thoughts?

Many thanks in advance for your help...

Comment: `12345abcde = 12345abcde` correct? Simply check if it matches.